# python select.select single socket alternative?

Tags: python, sockets

so, imagine I have only one socket that I need to manage for IO completion while its alive. With select.select() I would do

```
import socket
import select

a = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
a.setblocking(True)
connected = True

while connected:
    read, write, error = select.select([a], [a], [a])
    if read:
        #do stuff with data
    if write:
        #write to socket
```

is there not a better solution to checking if only one socket is readable/writable? I will only be dealing with a single socket object, and no more. I feel like this method was built in mind with managing multiple sockets as there could be a more effecient way to handle only one.

Answer (score 0):

select() is still the way to go, even for a single socket.  The only alternative (ignoring for the sake of discussion alternatives like poll(), which are similar to select()) would be blocking I/O, but if you're blocked in recv() you have no way to be woken up when the socket becomes ready-for-write, and vice versa if you're blocked in send().

So you might as well use select().  There's nothing inefficient about using it for a single socket.

Comment: Ok, i just felt like there could have been an alternative thats built in mind for only one socket, thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that even with one socket you're still (probably) multiplexing two different things:  input and output.